# How to make Laravel attribute cast get only one value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-10

My website incorporates multilingual functionality, allowing content to be displayed in various languages. To facilitate this, language-specific data is stored in the MySQL database within JSON fields. This approach enables flexible storage of language-specific information, with each JSON field containing data in different languages.

Example of the table:

articles - title - json - example:

`{"en": "English Title", "es": "Título en Español", "id": "Judul dalam Bahasa Indonesia"}`

And this is my Article model:

```
protected function casts(): array
{
    return [
        'title' => 'json',
        'resume' => 'json',
        'content' => 'json',
    ];
}
```

I tried to retrieve only the desired language value from the JSON attribute in my Laravel model using the following approach:

```
protected function title(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => $value['en'],
        set: fn ($value) => $value['en'],
    );
}
```

Despite various attempts, I'm still unable to retrieve only the desired language value. When attempting to access the specific language using syntax like $value->en, I encounter errors such as "Cannot access offset of type string on string".

My objective is to receive JSON data from articles in the format like articles[{ "id" : 1, "title" : "english title"}], containing only the necessary language data. However, I'm currently receiving the entire JSON object instead.

I've explored using Laravel's JSON.php class as documented, but the issue persists.

Additionally, I tried the following alternative approach:

`protected function getTitleAttribute() { return $this->title['en']; }`

However, the problem remains unresolved.

In summary, I'm struggling to access a single value from the JSON attribute in my model, and even defining a cast hasn't resolved the issue. This limitation hampers my ability to efficiently transmit only the necessary data to my React frontend.

Answer (score 0):

For one language only you can do something like this:

```
public function getTitleAttribute($value) { 
    return $value['en']; 
}

public function setTitleAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['title']['en] = value;
}
```

For multiple languages I would use something else:

```
public function getTitleByLanguage($language)
{
    return isset(this->title[$language]) ? this->title[$language] : 
         "No translation to ". $language . " available";
}

public function setTitleByLanguage($language, $value)
{
    $this->attributes['title'][$language] = $value;
}
```

I didn't test any of these methods, so please excuse potential typos :-) I'm just trying to get you on the right path.

**Addition**
As by @9uifranco mentioned you should cast to array instead of json. Sorry didn't see that at first.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your support, i casted it like you said and i got this: Cannot access offset of type string on string. and in mysql database its the field is set to json

 `` protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'array',
            'resume' => 'array',
            'content' => 'array',
        ];
    }

    public function getTitleAttribute($value) { 
        return $value['en']; 
    }
    
    public function setTitleAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['title']['en'] = $value;
    }``

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your attributes to `array` instead, and then get the value you want:

```php
protected function casts(): array
{
    return [
        'title' => 'array',
        'resume' => 'array',
        'content' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

or just use the `$casts` attribute:

```php
public $casts = [
    'title' => 'array',
    'resume' => 'array',
    'content' => 'array'
];
```

And then get the correct value by language:

```php
public function getTitleByLang($lang) { 
    return $this->attributes['title'][$lang] ?? null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, with your function i got [Undefined property: App\Models\Article::$title]

Comment: Try to change `getTitleByLang` function to this: `return $this->attributes['title'][$lang] ?? null;`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: i still get Cannot access offset of type string on string, it's like the json is not being casted as array

Comment: i tried to access it in a for each loop and i got that is really an array: array(3) { ["en"]=> string(13) "english title" ["id"]=> string(8) "id title" ["pt"]=> string(8) "pt title" }

Comment: That's weird behavior.. Can you complement your question with what you've tried so far (that will help for debugging)